# PHP MVC, view loop handling

Tags: php, templates

My controller returns a PDO array of several rows and columns. What is the best way of looping through the data in my view file? (or should I be doing more logic in the model?)

```
$user->getDetails();  //returns array in view


foreach($user->getDetails() as $row)  // Prehaps? But how to index without being explicit with column names?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>The best way or the approach being used in `MVC` is to keep your programming logic in the controller</del>, do the database related stuff in the model and format the layout in the view. In your case you should call the `$user->getDetails();` in the controller and then pass the result in the view then loop it to output the data, i.e.

In the controller you can populate a variable with `$user->getDetails()`

```
$user_details=$user->getDetails();
```

Then pass `$user_details` to the view when you load it and in the view loop it

```
foreach( $user_details as $row ){
   echo $row->id;
   echo $row->name;
}
```

If the result is an `array of arrays` instead of `an array of objects` then you can use as follows

```
foreach( $user_details as $row ){
   echo $row['d'];
   echo $row['name'];
}
```

**Update :**

1. The model is responsible to manage the data; it stores and retrieves entities used by an application, usually from a database, and contains the logic implemented by the application.
2. The view (presentation) is responsible to display the data provided by the model in a specific format. It has a similar usage with the template modules present in some popular web applications, like wordpress, joomla, …
3. The controller handles the model and view layers to work together. The controller receives a request from the client, invoke the model to perform the requested operations and send the data to the View. The view format the data to be presented to the user, in a web application as an html output.

**Reference:** [Model View Controller(MVC) in PHP](http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/) and [This](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/model-view-controller.html#controller).

Comment: **WRONG !**  Controller should contain neither business not presentation logic.

Comment: *The best way or the approach being used in MVC is to keep your programming logic in the controller, do the database related stuff in the model (..)* <= you said it here. Also, model is not a database abstraction.

Comment: @tereško, I'm confused, can you clarify more what did you mean ? I'm still now saying that controller should contain all the programming logic and from there you should call model functions declared in any model.

Comment: Thanks for your informed response. However why can I not call the function from within the view? I.e why assign it to a variable and then pass that to the view, is that not unnecessary code? Look forward to your reply. Thanks.

Comment: @SheikhHeera , the confusion come from fact you you do not understand how MVC should be structures : domain model contains **all** of business logic, views contain all of presentation logic and controller sends commands to views and model layer to change their state. Model is a layer and **not a single class**, and **view is not a template**. What you are describing is perversion of MVP (not MVC) pattern , perpetuated by Rails.

Comment: @SheikhHeera , before starting to write answers on subject of MVC, please research the classical MVC design pattern and MVC-inspired patterns, that have been created for web. Read some books maybe, like [PoEAA](http://www.amazon.com/Patterns-Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Martin/dp/0321127420) instead of codeigniter's manual.

Comment: @tereško, thanks for your advise but all I know about `MVC` from [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com) and I read a book about it and still now I read the articles online whenever I can, but thanks for your advise. :-)

Comment: @CraigWilson, As an example I can think that if I need to change/alter some programming logic (after development) of a site then I can only change it from the controller without altering the view but if I use view for programming logic too then I've to also change my code in the view as well.

Comment: @SheikhHeera , if you really want to understand MVC, then you should start by focusing on researching OOP (just because you know how to write class, does not mean that you undersstand OOP). I would recommend to start with reading everything you  can find about *SOLID principles*. Also lectures from [Miško Hevery](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w&feature=BFa&list=PLBDAB2BA83BB6588E)(first one is irrelevant) and Robert C. Martin are very recommended.

Comment: @SheikhHeera Though NOT doing enough research(!) and reading books your answer satisfied the OP, got highest upvotes, it reminds me the ever running battle between a successful business man and a business student.

Answer (score 2):

The point of the view is to run view-related logic and output results (i.e. take the data and format it as necessary...if it's a JSON view, output JSON. HTML output HTML, etc.), thus you're doing it right. Loop through it however you see fit, but without more details about your data structure, we can't say more than you already have figured out.

Answer (score 1):

```
    foreach( $user->getDetails() as $row ){
       echo $row->name;
       echo $row->id;
    }
```

You don't need to put the $user->getDetails() at the top, it will call the function in the foreach.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping this would be a suggested answer.

Answer (score 1):

The model layer should contain all the business logic. And it should not return anything to the controller. Instead the controller should just send messages to model layer structures.

The data from model layer should be extracted by view instance. And depending on nature of data, it would decide which templates to apply.

Views in MVC are supposed to contain all the presentation logic and ( in case of web-related MVC-inspired design patterns) deal with multiple templates. You should also be aware that there exists a 1:1 relation between views and controllers.

If if part of information, that view receives from model layer, is some sort of array, you have two choices. Either you take a template, which can render a single item and repeatedly generate the HTML/JSON/text/XML  fragment or you use a template , which expect to receive an array as variable and already contains a loop. The latter approach is usually the more pragmatic one, but each of them as a specific cons an pros.

Comment: Since I'm using CodeIgniter, I answered as [described here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html) in example. This `$data['query'] = $this->Blog->get_last_ten_entries();` is inside a controller and it retriving data from model, which means the modekis returning data to the controller and then the controller passing the data to date view as follws `$this->load->view('blog', $data);`.

Comment: May be you can clarify me if I'm misunderstanding something so I cal make myself clear, thanks.

Comment: Why are you pasting links to one of two works php frameworks in this topic ? What CI call "models" are activerecord instances. Activerecord is a melding of [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject)( which would be just a part of  well implemented  model layer ) and storage logic.

Comment: @SheikhHeera You will find that most "MVC" discussions have little relevance to CodeIgniter. CI does **not** implement the MVC pattern (despite whatever the CI wiki says), but rather something closer to MVP (but with templates). Basically, you'll never get CI to fully conform to the traditional MVC pattern.

Comment: @orourkek, Thanks but can you provide any online reference about proper `MVC` ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera I think the most fundamental difference between what [most of] the PHP frameworks call "MVC" (I'll call it "FMVC" for short) and actual traditional MVC is in the model layer. In "FMVC" patterns the model is usually just a class that gets and returns data from the DB. I'd suggest reading [this](http://bit.ly/R5g7JR), as it's currently the best explanation on SO of what an MVC Model is. And for a [quick] explanation of "FMVC" vs MVC, check out [this post](http://bit.ly/OA30zo), also by tereško.